# Errors with Python Classification and Regression Trees

Tags: python, tree, classification, regression

I'm learning how to use decision trees in python. I modified an example to import a csv file instead of using the iris dataset from this site:

http://machinelearningmastery.com/get-your-hands-dirty-with-scikit-learn-now/

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import urllib
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import metrics

# URL for the Pima Indians Diabetes dataset (UCI Machine Learning Repository)
url = "http://goo.gl/j0Rvxq"
# download the file
raw_data = urllib.urlopen(url)
# load the CSV file as a numpy matrix
dataset = np.loadtxt(raw_data, delimiter=",")
#print(dataset.shape)
# separate the data from the target attributes
X = dataset[:,0:7]
y = dataset[:,8]
# fit a CART model to the data
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(dataset.data, dataset.target)
print model
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DatasetTest2.py", line 24, in <module>
    model.fit(dataset.data, dataset.target)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'target'
```

I am not sure why this error is occuring. If I use the iris data set from the example it works just fine. Eventually, I need to be able to perform decision trees on csv files.

I've also tried the following code that also results in the same error:

```
# Import Python Modules
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import metrics
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Import Data
raw_data = pd.read_csv("DataTest1.csv")
dataset = raw_data.as_matrix()
#print dataset.shape
#print dataset
# separate the data from the target attributes
X = dataset[:,[2,3,4,7,10]]
y = dataset[:,[1]]
#print X
# fit a CART model to the data
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(dataset.data, dataset.target)
print model
```

Answer (score 0):

The `dataset` object that is imported in that example is not a plain table of data.  It is a special object that is set up with attributes like `data` and `target` so that it can be used as shown in the example.  If you have your own data, you will need to decide what to use as data and target.  From your example, it looks like you want to do `model.fit(X, y)`.